Ambiguity issues with 0.11.2 version of the vscode extension
Ever since I updated the vscode extension of rascal to version 0.11.2, I have been getting ambiguity warnings and errors when I try to test my syntax. I downgraded back to 0.11.1 and it works as it used to. I even tried it with other previous versions of the extension and they work like they should. What could be the cause?
This is a short example of what my codebase looks like.
module lang::testlang::Expressions

extend lang::std::Layout;
extend lang::exprlang::grammar::Expressions;


start syntax Program = Expr; 

syntax Expr
    = :neq2
    > left hashExp: Expr "#" Expr
    ;

With version 0.11.2 it returns an ambiguity error for a simple example like 2+2 but not 2 + 2. Testing out this same thing with 0.11.1 does not give me the warnings or return an ambiguity error

Hmm, this sounds like an unforseen regression, could you open up an issue on the rascal GitHub repo?

Alright. I'll do that.

We solved some issues in that release with how extend and grammars were working. It is either you ran into a regression, or the grammar depended on an unitented bug.
If you can make an minimal working example (and submit it to the issue tracker), we can help figure it out.
